# Aluminium Oxide as Dehydrating agent

Tags: reaction-mechanism, metal, catalysis

According to this [paper](http://beta.chem.uw.edu.pl/people/AMyslinski/nowy/zarzadzanie/26ME.pdf) on **dehydration by $\ce{Al2O3}$**,

> Dehydroxylation causes a surface defects as Lewis acidic centers (unsaturated $\ce{Al^3+}$ ions) and basic Lewis centers ($\ce{O^2-}$ ions) creation. Water molecules deactivate Lewis centers and create **strongly acidic Brönsted’s centers**. Alcohols dehydration reaction performs on Brönsted’s active centers where hydroxyl groups disconnect proton from alcohol molecule. During reaction alcohol molecule adsorbed on aluminium oxide surface reacts with proton.

But I am not able to understand what they are trying to convey here.

Comment: I have revised my question and added other points also. It is now clearer than before.

Comment: Regarding the flag you've raised on your own question as to why it has been closed as HW, I think the reason is obvious if you read [the information in the reason for closing](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). The question itself is all right, but you are supposed to add your thoughts and/or demonstrate the research done prior to asking.

Comment: Simply stating "*I don't understand X*" isn't constructive. Something like "*I've read this paper [ref] and it claims X, whereas my textbook [ref] says Y, but I think it's Z because of this, that and the other*" would be much better and help others help you since we would have better understanding what exactly you are having difficulties with.

Answer (score 3):

Alumina absorbs water to give aluminium oxide hydroxide, a solid which removes the water from the reaction environment.

According to the paper by Pethrick et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10/chcqs8)]:

> Aluminium oxide exists in several forms which on addition of water give a complex range of oxide-hydroxide; boehmite, bayerite and gibbsite.

#### References

1. Pethrick, R. A.; Hayward, D.; Jeffrey, K.; Affrossman, S.; Wilford, P. Investigation of the Hydration and Dehydration of Aluminium Oxide-Hydroxide Using High Frequency Dielectric Measurements between 300 KHz–3 GHz. *J Mater Sci* **1996**, 31 (10), 2623–2629. https://doi.org/10/chcqs8.

Comment: Is there any kind of mechanism involved in the reaction?

Comment: There is a reaction between the alumina surface and free water with water adding to the aluminium atom, but afaik that is as much as can be said.